# Push a view when click the tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to push a view when I click the cell of my tableview.The code is as followed:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.tag == todoTableViewTag) {
        NSLog(@"aa");
        ViewControlleraaa* testvc = [[ViewControlleraaa alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControlleraaa" bundle:nil];    
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:testvc animated:YES];
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

but it does not work at all.

I have 
ViewControlleraaa.h ViewControlleraaa.m and ViewControlleraaa.xib 
but I did nothing except creating them.

So where is the problem?

Comment: Does the code fire at all? Do you ever see "aa" logged to the console?

Comment: @mbm29414 yes , and the testvc is not nil. So I can not figure out where is the problem!

Comment: What about `self.navigationController`? Is it `nil`? Maybe you need to embed your view controller in a navigation controller?

Comment: Did you check if the method is hit at all? Maybe the tag or the variable is not what you think it is ....

Comment: @mbm29414  Ooooooooh!!!!   self.navigationController is nil !!!!!! Thanks a lotttttttttttt!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'generic' segue from your table view controller to ViewControlleraaa and use 'performSegueWithIdentifier'. If that approach is not possible to execute then you may want to try 'presentViewController' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a manual segue from your table view controller to ViewControlleraaa.  Then, as the answerer above me said, you can use performSegueWithIdentifier to call the segue.  If you should ever need the table view controller to push any data to the ViewControlleraaa, you can do so using the "prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender" method. The destinationViewController property of "segue" is ViewControlleraaa.

Here's a link to a YouTube video, in case you need any additional help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XApYtAlRDVE

Answer (score 0):

Check self.navigationController is not nil then surly it will work fine.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];    
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```